# cascade delete for dynamic target

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, microservices

Given a `comments` microservice that stores comments of different "commentable"-targets this is the internal data schema:

```
CREATE TABLE comment (
    id          bigserial   PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     bigint      NOT NULL,
    target      varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    target_id   bigint      NOT NULL,
    text        text        NOT NULL,
    timestamp   bigint      NOT NULL
);
```

As you can see there are no foreign keys because the domain is loosely coupled to different other services.
The `(target, target_id)` define a specific target the comment belongs to. The target might also be another comment (enabling comment-trees).

**What is a good approach to efficiently cascading deletes** if there are no cascades on the DB layer?

I think that this needs to be done on the service layer, because the repositories do not actually know each other in a microservice architecture. But how to do this efficiently?

I think of this approaches for now:

Delete the root entity and mark all **direct** descendants for garbage collection. If not running, start a garbage collector asynchronously to remove the marked comments and mark the next descendants for garbage collection. Run until no more garbage is present.

- Pros:

  - user facing operations are fast
  - Easy to implement, comprehend and reason about.
- Cons:

  - temporary inconsistencies
  - takes `n` runs to clean garbage, where `n` is the depth of the comments tree (comments on comments), but when multiple entities are removed in parallel the garbage collector can merge the deletes of the "current layer".

  The cons seem acceptable because time is not critical for garbage collection and non-connected data is never visible to users.

Comment: I worked with these kind of issues around 4 years, the best approach is use a streamer queue to delete/update some tables by micro-service.

Comment: The best approach is to redesign and introduce proper foreign keys...

Comment: you can use a messaging system(rabbitMq,kafka,sqs). Generate the delete event and listen in microservice and delete the enities.

Comment: Would you guys then recursively emit delete events per comment to propagate the cascading to the comments on comments? The only other option I see is to redesign it in such way that comments on comments have a different table structure to do the cascading in the db layer (which is possible because the service manages all comments and hence can establish a foreign key on its self)

Comment: @Laurenz Albe  how would you introduce a foreign key to a database sitting behind a different service API? To my knowledge this is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean that the tables are in different databases? Then forget my comment. If it is just a different API, but the same database, then that shouldn't be an obstacle.

Comment: Yes it is a different database.